# How does one install a camera driver from a c file, and what is this driver doing?

Tags: software-installation, drivers, camera

I need to install a driver for a MT9M032 CMOS Image Sensor USB machine vision camera made by Aptina (formerly Micron).

I am working on a Macintosh running OS X 10.9.1 and am new to Linux/Unix when it comes to this sort of thing.  When one comes across a c-file for a camera driver (see driver below), how does one go about installing it?  What exactly is the driver doing to my system such that it will now recognize the camera?

https://github.com/dorimanx/Dorimanx-SG2-I9100-Kernel/blob/master-jelly-cm-aokp/drivers/media/i2c/mt9m032.c

Please also see the conversation below regarding a patch of the driver:
https://linuxtv.org/patch/10062/

The bottom line is my computer does not recognize the camera, and I know that drivers have been written (i.e. see above driver for MT9M032 CMOS Image Sensor from Micron). If you think there is a better approach I should be taking please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the software from that GitHub URL you should notice there is a `Makefile` that's included. I would download the entire project directory and run the command `make`. After it's done you'll likely have `.ko` files generated, these are Linux Kernel modules (drivers).

Again utilizing the `Makefile` there should be a target included called `install`. You can run it like so, `make install`. This should put the `.ko` files in their appropriate locations.

Once they're "installed" you can load them and unload them like so:

```
$ sudo modprobe mt9m032

-or-

$ sudo rmmod mt9m032
```

Answer (score 1):

The source code is for Linux only, yet you mention you are on a Mac.  If the target machine is not Linux its not going to without some effort.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to contact a person who worked on the driver.  This is their response:

The MT9M032 is a camera sensor only. It can't be connected directly to a
computer, so you've used a demo board from Micron/Aptina in this case to act
as a bridge between the sensor and USB. This is a common design (although the
bridge type may vary).

You will need two drivers to support your device, one driver for the sensor
and one driver for the bridge. The mt9m032 driver I've worked on should be
usable as a sensor driver, but you're missing a bridge driver for the DEMO2
board itself. I'm not aware of any such Linux kernel driver. That would be an
interesting project, but would involve quite a lot of work.

To summarize, there are drivers for the camera sensor boards and drivers for the usb bridge board.  Both must be written and available.  Furthermore, the author said the above camera driver would not be useful on a Macintosh unless it is running Linux.